# can't load require_dependency

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I'm trying to use `require_dependency` from `ActiveSupport` library in pry:

```
require 'active_support'  #=> true
require_dependency 'test' #=> NoMethodError: undefined method  
                          #=> `require_dependency' for main:Object
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveSupport used to be pretty evil by loading a ton of stuff on require.  The "kitchen sink" approach opened a lot of core classes up and changed their behavior (like JSON).  This caused incompatibilities/problems with other gems and code that expected core ruby functions to behave like their vanilla selves.

So now requiring just active_support does not load anything.

see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html

in your case you probably will need `require 'active_support/core_ext'`

Comment: It works with this line: require 'active_support/dependencies'

Comment: Yes thanks for that it will help people in the future that see this.