# Make require_dependency work from within any Ruby file in a Rails project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to have `require_dependency` work from a Rails application without using:

```
require 'active_support/dependencies'
```

*(That solution was suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021955/cant-load-require-dependency) Q&A).*

I've created a new Rails application using version 4.1.5 called `TestRails`. In the `lib` folder, I've added a new Ruby file called `test_rails.rb` in which I placed:

```
require_dependency "plugin/instance"  # << fails here

module TestRails
  def self.doSomethingAwesome
      # some real work here
  end
end
```

Within the definition of `class Application` in `application.rb`, I added:

```
require 'test_rails`
```

to load the `lib` file above.

However, when I attempt to run the application, I'll get an error:

```
TestRails/lib/test_rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': 
undefined method `require_dependency' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

If I explicitly add `require 'active_support/depdencies'` the `require_dependency` line will work. I'd been browsing the GitHub repository for Discourse [here](https://github.com/discourse/discourse) and their code uses `require_dependency` without the explicit `require` I've used, but I couldn't seem to discover how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

Discourse has this line in Gemfile:

```
gem 'seed-fu', '~> 2.3.5'
```

seed-fu requires activerecord which in turn requires active_support/dependencies. See [activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb)